# How to add symbolic variables to Symmetric Functions algebra in Sagemath

Tags: python, sage

I'm defining some operators in the algebra Symqt = SymmetricFunctions(QQ['q','t'].fraction_field()), and I need a third variable.

If I add it to the base field, however, I'm unable to evaluate it; if I try to define a polynomial ring over Symqt, I'm unable to multiply coefficients and variables.

```
from sage.combinat.q_analogues import *
from sage.combinat.sf.sfa import *
F = QQ['q','t','u'].fraction_field()
F.inject_variables(verbose = False)
Symqt = SymmetricFunctions(F)
Symqt.inject_shorthands(verbose = False)
(u*s[2]).subs(u=1)
```

gives u*s[2] (doesn't evaluate), while

```
from sage.combinat.q_analogues import *
from sage.combinat.sf.sfa import *
F = QQ['q','t'].fraction_field()
F.inject_variables(verbose = False)
Symqt = SymmetricFunctions(F)
Symqt.inject_shorthands(verbose = False)
R = PolynomialRing(Symqt,'u')
u*s[2]
```

raises an error (can't multiply stuff in R with stuff in Symqt).

Comment: You may find quicker help for such specialized questions on ask.sagemath.org or sage-support@googlegroups.com - good luck.